Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial and $f(x)$ a line that is tangent to $p(x)$ at $r.$ Why must $p(x)-f(x)$ have a root of $r$ with even multiplicity?
I recently came across a problem which needed the fact that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial and $f(x)$ is a line with $f(x)$ being tangent to $p(x)$ at point $r$, then the function $p(x)-f(x)$ must have a root $r$ with even multiplicity.
My thought of why this is true is because it must be tangent on a "U-shaped" area of $p(x)$ and when this is subtracted by $f(x)$ it retains its "U-shape" at that area. Also, $p(r)=f(r),$ so $p(x)-f(x)$ must have a zero at $r,$ and it is a "U-shape" at that area meaning it must have even multiplicity because it "bounces off" of the x-axis.
I don't think this is even right and definitely not a solid proof. Could someone give me a hint to figuring this out?

I think it is not true. Consider $p(x) = x^3$ and point $x = 0$.

What is true is that the root $x=r$ of $p(x) - f(x)$ has multiplicity at least $2$.  It could be any integer $\ge 2$, odd or even.

Perhaps you have added assumptions, e.g. that the line is on the same side of the graph of $p(x)$ for $x < r$ as it is for $x > r$.

As others have pointed out, the correct statement is either that the root has multiplicity $\ge 2$ or that "tangent" implies that the curves don't cross at the point of tangency.
Here is an argument with no calculus. We need a definition of tangency which does not refer to derivatives, which can be done as follows: say that two curves $y = f(x), y = g(x)$ are tangent without crossing at a point $x = a$ if they intersect at $a$ (so $f(a) = g(a)$) and also in some sufficiently small neighborhood of $a$ we either have $f(x) \ge g(x)$ for all $x$ in the neighborhood or $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x$ in the neighborhood, so one of the curves must lie above the other near $a$.
(Of course this definition doesn't really do the intuitively correct thing if $f, g$ are not differentiable at $a$, but it's good enough for polynomials.)
Now suppose $f, g$ are two polynomials which are tangent at $a$ without crossing. Then $f(x) - g(x)$ is divisible by $x - a$. We can write
$$f(x) - g(x) = (x - a)^k h(x)$$
where $h(a) \neq 0$. In order for $f, g$ to be tangent without crossing the values of this polynomial at $x = a \pm \varepsilon$ for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$ must have the same sign; these are given by $(\pm \varepsilon)^k h(a \pm \varepsilon)$ where $h(a \pm \varepsilon)$ is near $h(a) \neq 0$, so for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$ does not change sign. This means in order for this whole expression to not change sign $k$ must be even, as desired.

When you say tangent, I assume you also mean not crossing! This is not inherently implied by the definition.
Without loss of generality let's say $f$ lies below $p$ in the $\delta-$neighborhood around $r$. Say $f(r)=p(r)$ and $f'(r)=p'(r)$, but for all $0<\epsilon<\delta$, we have $f(r\pm \epsilon)<p(r\pm \epsilon)$. Now let $q=p-f$, so $q$ has a root at $r$. Consider now the Taylor series of $q$ centered at $r$, $q(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{(n)}(x-r)\frac{(x-r)^n}{n!}$.
The multiplicity of the root is the index of the first non-zero coefficient of the power series. As others commented, it is easy to check that $q^{(0)}(x-r)=q^{(1)}(x-r)=0$, but to show the multiplicity is even, use the fact that $q(r\pm \epsilon)\geq 0$ for all small $\epsilon$.
As one more hint, suppose the multiplicity is $k$, and consider $\lim_{x\to r}\frac{q(x)}{(x-r)^k}$.
